# Comparar objeto según dos atributos

Tags: java, array

Tengo una clase llamada Celda con dos parámetros (precio y valor). Necesito ordenar una lista de objetos Celda, dando prioridad a aquellas con mayor valor, y en el caso de que dos tengan el mismo valor, se da más importancia a la que tenga menos precio. Este es mi código para comparar según valores. Cómo modificarlo para que además tenga en cuenta el precio?

```
     static final Comparator<Celda> VALUE_COMPARATOR = (Celda c1, Celda c2) -> 
     c1.getValue().compareTo(c2.getValue());
```

La llamada es luego implementada de la siguiente forma, siendo Values una lista de objetos tipo Celda.

```
    Collections.sort(values, Celda.VALUE_COMPARATOR);
```

Alguna idea sobre cómo solucionar mi problema? Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1):

Primero debes comprar el valor y si esta compración devuelve `0`, quiere decir que ambos son iguales, por lo que procedes a comprar el precio que será entonces quien decidirá. Pero solo en el caso que el valor sea igual en ambos objetos:

```
Comparator<Celda> VALUE_COMPARATOR = (Celda c1, Celda c2) -> {
    int value = c2.getValue().compareTo(c1.getValue());
    if (value == 0) {
        value = c1.getPrice().compareTo(c2.getPrice());
    }
    return value;
};
```

Nota que para conseguir que se ordene en orden descendente según el valor, tengo que comprar el objeto 2 con respecto al objeto 1.

```
int value = c2.getValue().compareTo(c1.getValue());
```

Pero ya que utilizas el JDK8, o uno superior, puedes utilizar las mejoras realizadas a la clase `Comparartor`, para realizar comparaciones utilizando programación funcional. Quedaría de este modo:

```
Comparator<Celda> VALUE_COMPARATOR = Comparator.comparing(Celda::getValue).reversed().thenComparing(Celda::getPrice);
```

Nota como se reduce el código considerablemente, incluso se hace más legible.